# Capture Application Output Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm an italian programmer (i started a new job from 2 weeks).
I have to made a program that permit me to print some ticket from a touchscreen monitor and pay it.
For the payment i use a cashflow mei model 7900.
Now the problem is that there are not some code example for delphi and the API demo is wrote in c#.
I thought to use the exe demo for communicating with the cashflow by capturing output and input it on my delphi application.
For example in delphi i can capture the output of a console and input into a textbox, i want to capture the command start of demo app and input into my delphi app that will do some things.
Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture Console in Delphi 2009 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905450/capture-console-in-delphi-2009-and-above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some similar questions here on SO, please start with them:

[Capture Console in Delphi 2009 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4905450/850848)
[How to read from an external console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526994/850848)
[Delphi 6 - read console app's output while running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212176/850848)